# Rails I18n overlay for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

We're using Rails with I18n for a web application running for users in multiple countries. To handle different languages we're setting the locale based on the TLD. Now, we have an important customer in one country that requires custom translations. To handle this, we would like to overlay a few translations for that specific customer.

Right now we're loading the locales as usual, but also add a folder to the `I18n.load_path` if the session belongs to the specific customer and then run `I18n.backend.reload!`. This works well, and we only have to add the keys that needs custom translations for the customer in question. What's less great is that this changes the translations for everybody using the same language.

What's the recommended way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out by adding a custom locale for which I added a fallback to the language in question. Works well.